# OnePageScroll iPad touch scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, ipad, jquery-plugins

I have problem with onepagescroll plugin on iPad device. When I click on bullets everythink works fine, but when I trying to scroll there is no one page scroll effect. I can only use normal scroll from current section (where I am from clicking on bullets) down. Scrolling up from current section is not possible. I get no error in console.

Elsewhere (desktop - Chrome, Firefox, Safari etc.) works OK. I have disabled feature on mobile.

What could be wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Code? Sample? A sniff of a prototype? Anything? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend you to try [fullPage.js](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/) instead. 
It provides support for mobile phones and touch devices as well as for old browsers such as IE 8 and 9.

Comment: Thank you. I think that the problem was with jquery.mb.YTPlayer in combination with onePageScroll. Jquery.mb.YTPlayer for background video creates some sort of overlay over whole section. In that case touch event couldn't be detected at all.